# Android's Content is not allowed in Prolog while adding font

Tags: android, fonts

I'm coding my first android app and I've got this following error:

```
"Content is not allowed in Prolog"
```

When I tried to compile which is showing me that the font is the issue. I checked most of the answers on this problem on stackoverflow, but everyone was telling that the font should be inside  **src/main/assets** folder and it will work. The problem is, my font was there since the beginning.
Android Studio version is 1.3.2, project is using sdk23 to build and 17 as minimum if that matters. Also I'm pasting the code I'm setting the font if that's important anyhow.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "digital-7.ttf");
TimerClock.setTypeface(tf);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: "I've got this strange error "Content is not allowed in Prolog" when I tried to compile which is showing me that the font is the issue" -- no, you have a problem with one of your XML files, where you have characters before the `<?xml ...` stuff at the top of the file.

Comment: can you post the error log here ??

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\PROJEKTY\Android\BombFun\app\src\main\res\fonts\digital-7.ttf:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

This is what I get in the logs

Comment: My God... I didn't notice the src isnt the same... It seems I put the font into other folder by a mistake before... The font was in the correct folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same exact issue using Android Studio Version 1.4.1.
I removed all the fonts from my assets folder and saved them to a temporary location. There was also a lingering png file in there that I moved directly to the top level res folder. Then I reran Android Studio and exited it. Then I copied all of the fonts back into the asset folder and opened Android Studio again, and the Prolog error mysteriously disappeared when it built.

Hope that works for you!